# UV Unwrapping so that every face takes the whole UV?

Tags: texturing, uv

Trying to make so that when I unvrap each quads takes the whole UV squard; i tried scaling down to 0 then scaling up but somehow loosing information ?

Is there a faster way to individually select all faces and make them fit ?

Thanks !

[image: U]

Comment: That would be _U_ UV unwrap > _Reset_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to illustrate Robin's comment (and show off my gif skillz)

1. Select the whole mesh
2. Go *UV > Reset*
3. Done

[image]

Comment: one thumb up for your gif skillz

Comment: best in the hood

Comment: Duh. I feel so dumb bruh ... I guess some are made to be programmers, some 3d artists. Thanks !

Comment: @DiscoFever Don't feel dumb, maybe you'll help me with Drupal some day... :)

Comment: I get stage-fright.. rehearse a million times, and then blow it... :)

Comment: @JachymMichal anytime mate :)